# Python - Understaning CSV Module and line_num object

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, module, python-3.3

In my code, I would like to be able to print the line number if an error is found during processing (called in another piece of code), but I'm having trouble doing this using the `line_num` object. Here is my code for a .csv that is 4 rows long:

```
with open(inFile, 'U') as inFH:
    csvReader = csv.reader(inFH, delimiter = ',')
    header = csvReader.__next__()
    lineNum = csvReader.line_num

    for row in csvReader:
        print(lineNum)
```

when I execute this code, I see this in the console:

```
1
1
1
1
```

My expectation is that I would see:

```
1
2
3
4
```

It almost looks like the code is printing the index and not the line number...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`lineNum` is not changed after the first assignment. Printing it inside loop print same value repeatedly.

Why don't you print `csvReader.line_num` as follow?

```
for row in csvReader:
    print(csvReader.line_num)
```